# I cannot apply my addEventListener to every '.word' class

Tags: dom-events

I'm trying to make certain things happen when I click on my '.words' class and it works if I just target one (using the document.querySelector). But I want to target every element with class '.words' and apply the changes when I click on them. For some reason I cannot figure out how to do this. Here's my code:

```
var food = document.querySelectorAll('.words');
function chicken()  {
   for (let i = 0; i < food.length; i++){
     if(food[i].style.color === 'white'){
       food[i].style.color = 'red';
     } else if(food[i].style.color === 'red'){
       food[i].style.color = 'blue';
     } else {
       food[i].style.color = 'white';
     }
   }
}

food[i].addEventListener('click', chicken, false);
```

Comment: Your last line is outside the `for` loop, and outside the function, so it has no idea what `i` is.

Comment: Yeah that was the problem, thanks man.